How to get file categories with size from Azure Netapps
We have a Azure Netapps file storage (around 4 TB). We need to monitor the list file formats stored in Netapps storage along with storage size.
Example: Expected output

Pdf files - 100 - 200 MB
Jpeg files - 10 - 20 MB

And so on.
Is there any tools available to get these details faster?
We tried with WizTree tool after attaching as a network drive in Windows. But it's taking too much time to compute the expected output.
